# how to save python workspace with plots in a file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pickle

I would like to store the work done on IPython on a file. Say that I did a plot of sin(x)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.plot as plt
import pickle
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.sin(np.pi*x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
pickle.dumb(['x': x, 'y':y], open("save.p", "wb"))
```

to take data saved on "save.p" on another Ipython interpreter I just have to type

```
a = pickle.load( open("save.p", "rb"))
```

and here everything is ok, but how can I save even the plot I did? I tried to replace

```
pickle.dumb(['x': x, 'y':y], open("save.p", "wb"))
```

with

```
pickle.dumb(['x': x, 'y':y, 'fig': fig, 'ax': ax], open("save.p", "wb"))
```

but it doesn't provide me any plot. What can you suggest to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I believe it should be pickle.dump(), not pickle.dumb

2) Simple matplotlib figures are pickleable, but I would not recommend it as a long-term storage of them since you might not be able to open them with a different version of matplotlib. When you pickle, you should pickle the entire object you want to save, for example `pickle.dump(fig, open( "save.p", "wb" ))`. If you start using some more advanced code, for example things implemented in c or the Python `lambda`-expressions it wont work...

3) Regarding the local workspace I do not have a solution. You can maybe use the `locals()`-function, but that will give you everything in the `local`-namespace. Perhaps you can save `local`before anything has been run (but after all imports!) and then compare it to the `local`-list after you have executed your code? When you have this reduced list you can just pickle it again or use `numpy.save` to save it.  This is however just a wild-guess solution...